# Which between "crap" and "shit" is more rude?

Tags: slang

According to the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english), *shit* is defined as "(i) Faeces, (ii) Something worthless; rubbish; nonsense", whereas *crap* is defined as "(i) Something of extremely poor quality, (ii) Excrement". In addition, to me as a non-native speaker, those carry the same meaning when used in the following sentences:

> This book is crap.
>   This book is shit.

While neither are to be used in polite conversation ("This book is worthless" would be more appropriate), which of the two words is more rude?

Comment: Profanity is perfectly on topic and acceptable here. :)

Comment: Not only that, but neither *crap* nor *shit* are slang. Slang [is](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slang) "very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language, as *Hit the road*." *Shit* and *crap* are the exact opposite of slang.

Comment: I am migrating this to ELL because any native speaker will easily identify *crap* as a euphemism for *shit*, and as such less rude by definition.

Comment: @user1068446 - True, but technically the terms under discussion are scatology. Bad language is generally divided into three categories: profanity (uses religious terms), obscenity (refers to sex) and scatology (refers to bodily waste).

Comment: @ЯegDwight honestly, as a native (American English) speaker, I find them both to be equally rude and offensive swear words...I don't see one as being any more so than the other.

Comment: @Cupcake you can say "crap" on TV. End of story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I view *shit* as a swear word, *crap* as a rude word and *poo (poop)* as a word suitable for children to use. *Shit* always seems to be a bit of an Americanism to me which weakens its impact a little for my ears, rather like an Englishman calling someone a *motherfucker*. It just doesn't sound right; it's like listening to a non-native speaker swearing in English, it doesn't convey the feeling.

I would also add that *shite* is a stronger word in my profanisaurus.

In order of 'sweariness'

> That book was shite
>   That book was shit
>   That book was crap
>   That book was poo (poop)

Comment: In decreasing order of sweariness, you mean?  If so, I agree other than to swap the first two.

Comment: @Poldie Yes, decreasing order of sweariness. In my opinion _shite_ is much stronger that _shit_ when used as an offensive term in British English.

Comment: No, *shite* is a polited form of *shit*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did say it's my opinion but I'd rather be called _An old shit_ than _An old shite_ any day of the week; it would lead me to believe that the speaker wasn't as tough as they want to appear and I'd beat _the living shite_ out of them with my cane.

Comment: Surely these rankings are largely subjective. FWIW, I've always ranked 'crap' as 'worse' than 'shit', which appears in the KJV.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, they are completely subjective, but the OP wanted a ranking so I gave him mine. It's a bit like  _God damn it_ and _Gosh darn it_. I don't find religious terms offensive at all and those two are equally as bland as each other, but I know people who wouldn't be happy to hear me say 'christ on a bike', the same way I prefer _shite_ over _shit_ when I want to be offensive (maybe I'm not offending people as much as I could though if the majority think _shit_ is more offensive than _shite_).

Comment: I'm from England, and shite always sounds like a Scottish version.  It's certainly imported from somewhere, and not something I ever heard growing up.

Comment: @Poldie I'm not sure we **can** _import_ anything from Scotland unless and until they choose independence. And I think we should avoid shite; N Sea gas is OK.

Comment: @Frank Questions that are/turn out to prompt only overly subjective answers are off-topic. Your 'completely subjective' has prompted my close vote (though when you think about it, labelling a question 'calls for opinions rather than factual answers' is also subjective).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well I think that's a pretty _shit_ thing to do, almost verging on _shite_. No, seriously, had it been _shit_ or _poo_ then there would be almost total agreement, with two words so close together on the 'sweariness' scale there's never going to be a consensus. However, when measuring on the (newly invented probably) Simpson Scale, Bart has used the word _crap_ but I don't believe he has ever used the word _shit_.

Comment: As an American English speaker, I consider both "shit" and "crap" to be swear words.

Answer (score 4):

Perceptions may well have been influenced over the last 20 years or so by so influential a figure as B Simpson using the word 'crap' freely, as Frank mentions. Perhaps there are regional differences in taboo-ranking; Collins reflects my perception (in the UK) that 'crap' is the more taboo. (AHD doesn't differentiate wrt degree of tabooness.) From previous contributions here, the general situation in the US seems to be the opposite. But subjectiveness is unavoidable in these areas.

**shit**

> AHD: **shit** Vulgar Slang
>
> Collins: [no warning tag]

**crap**

> AHD: **crap 1**  Vulgar Slang
>
> Collins: Usage: This word was formerly considered to be taboo, and it
>   was labelled as such in previous editions of Collins English
>   Dictionary. However, it has now become acceptable in speech, although
>   some older or more conservative people may object to its use

Answer (score 3):

*Crap* is generally considered more acceptable than *shit.*

Answer (score 1):

To me, your second example is more rude. According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Crap,%20shit,%20Crap,%20Shit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Crap;,c0;.t1;,shit;,c0;.t1;,Crap;,c0;.t1;,Shit;,c0) it is also the most used.

Comment: According to the Ngram, it's the most used _in published writing_.

Answer (score -1):

While degrees of offensiveness are hard to quantify, and YMMV, I'd argue that "crap" is less offensive than "shit", for a purely practical reason. There exists a widespread and popular dice game called "craps", and its use serves to keep "crap" from becoming an entirely offensive word.

Answer (score -4):

'Crap' derives from the name of Mr Thomas Crapper, the Victorian sanitary engineer who developed the then existing flushing water closet. And whilst 'crap' is less offensive as a term for excrement than 'shit', it is still not something one uses in polite company.

Comment: Sorry, that [myth was busted](http://www.snopes.com/business/names/crapper.asp)... it _is_ an amusing reference though :)

Comment: I'm afraid the Crapper story is, well... crap. See the discussion at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=18793

Comment: @oerkelens If you and Erik Kowal will insist on paying attention to the 'crap' on the internet you will continue to be misinformed. There is an entry in the Oxford Dictionary of National Biography (a very reliable source) by an accredited historian, namely Anita McConnell, which indicates that though TC may not have built the original WC he was a leading developer and improver of the system and his name is the undoubted etymology of 'crap' and 'crapper'. http://www.oxforddnb.com/view/article/55389

Comment: Thomas Crapper born 1836, first reference to crap 1846 in the OED apparently as 'crapping ken'; an outside toilet. I think we can stop all this crap now. :)

Comment: Well, if Anita McConnell explains how Mr.Crap at the tender age of ten gave rise to his name being used in this way, both the accredited historian and the OED (not the lowliest of references I'd think) can still both be right :)

Comment: @WS2 - Perhaps you'd care to refute the information in the debunking instead of simply behaving like a toddler who has been refused cake.